# ubuntu 16.04 - hdmi display not reconnecting

Tags: hdmi

I am using :

Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, Official Intel Display Drivers (also occurs with default), Intel ComputeStick, Connected to an LG television via HDMI

If I do any of the following:

1) Change input to a different source and reboot while changed

2) Unplug the television and reboot while off

3) Turn off the television and reboot while off

4) Disconnect the stick HDMI from the television and reboot and then plug back in to television

When I turn the television back on or return to the proper input source, the television indicates there is no signal.

*(Note that the above is how I guarantee to reproduce the problem, sometimes the loss of signal occurs even if I don't reboot in those scenarios)*

To get a better idea of what was going on, I installed TeamViewer. I replicated the above and then remotely accessed via TeamViewer. I then opened a terminal and used xrandr and received this output:

```
$ xrandr
HDM1 disconnected
```

When I ran this command, the television was turned on and was at the correct input and the stick was connected via hdmi.

I use this for digital signage and the television is mounted to the point where I must use a ladder to physically reach the stick to manually reboot (all wires go into the wall behind the television). As such, I would like very much to be able to just turn the television off and on and change input, etc. without having to manually reboot. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I encounter the exact same problem with an Intel NUC6CAYH on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I never did find a solution beyond the reboot of the stick.